# How to use TransactionScope while following mvc4 dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

As i am new to `Dependency Injection` concept. I am following Database first approach and using `Entity Framework`.

I have created `IRepository` Interface containing all crude operation.
and i have class Repository class  implementing this`interface

I am creating the classes and interfaces of db tables and implementing these two into them.`How can I use Transaction scope while Insertion and Update.

And How to use joins in controller while following this pattern

Comment: Could you show code example with comments where you want to use TransactionScope?

Comment: As we know that in dependency injection we treat all entities separately So Suppose we want to Perform the Insertion into three Tables and Condition is that if on insertion on two tables succeeds and fails on third table the whole 3 tables insertion should be Rollback. So can Please Tell me How this can be Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this three tables present three linked entities, you should use navigation properties in your E-F mapping. In this case, you create one entity with navigation properties and save it. Transaction will be addwd automatically.

If your entities is not linked with navigation properties, you should have in your repository special method, that will add all three entities to db and in this method you should use `TransactionScope`